# Binding more click events on body will affect application the performance?

Tags: jquery

My web app has many jquery custom components, in which most of them needs outside(body click) click to hide them. So the body have many click events with different namespace. Today my superior told me that application becomes slow (I have recently added some  body click events)

Binding many click events will affect the applications overall performance. If it does, how shall i increase the performance without affecting the existing functionalities.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have as many click events to the same element as you want without worrying about performance issues.

**Instead of doing this**

```
$('body').click(function(){
1....
})

$('body').click(function(){
2....
})
```

**Do this**

```
$('body').click(function(){
1....
2....
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Are all the clickevents necessary in the webapplication as it is? Or are some clickevents only relevent when another event has occured (ex click)? You could bind the clickevents in the callback of another event if the second event is irrelevant when the first event has not been executed yet. This will decrease your initial JS events and will do good to your performance.